# Burger menu from wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

I'm just starting my programming but I need help.

I built my site from wordpress template. Made a lot of customization on my own but I have trouble by creating BURGER MENU on mobile devices.

I'm not sure how I can rewrite chosen template navigation bar menu to burger. Let me know if anyone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help we need to see some code. If you don't have any to show, chances are this will not be answered and may be flagged for deletion. However, there are many resources online, try Googling `how to make a hamburger menu`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it a few different ways, but personally, it's easier to place it with javascript and hide it with css...

Usually, you would create an element with javascript and attach it to a location on your page. For the burger itself, you've got the option of using drop-shadows, three divs or the unicode character for it. You can read more about those options here: https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/

Finally, if you want to add animation to your menu items (for opening / closing ) here's something that you can read to understand how it's possible to achieve: https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... I just dont know where to start. How to place it with javascript.

Comment: Just start with putting `<script></script>` somewhere near the bottom of the page. If you're using jQuery, you could do something like `<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){ /* do your js here */ } );</script>`

Comment: Hello Andrew, thank you so much. Im working on it right now. tHANK YOU FOR YOU HELP!